# Pass parameter to block function

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, javascript

How to pass java script variable value as a parameter in block function.

```
Ex:-
javaScrip code:-
var temp='US';
 alert("<?php echo $this->getAdd(temp)?>");
```

where getadd($temp) is function in edit.block.

Comment: You can't do that in PHP, let alone Magento.

Answer (score 1):

We can not call a function with a parameter, you can call it as without the parameter and got the right response in the alert. 
If you modify the alert response you need to call before js and get the array of response as you like to alert inbox.

JS:

Ex:-

```
var temp='US';
alert("<?php echo $this->getAdd(); ?>");
```

I hope it will help you. 
Or for more information go to magento call a function.